# Custom style for a vector layer

Tags: openlayers

I would like to change the default style for vector features in a map layer.
Reading the doc, I wrote the following:

```
var myStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({fill: true,fillColor: "#ff0000"});
var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('CODLayer', {style: myStyle});
```

But I get every feature black...do you have an idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: I solved in the following way:`var myStyle = {fill: true,fillColor: "#ff0000"}; var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('CODLayer', {style: myStyle});` taking example from [here](http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/ollatency.html).

Comment: You should put that as an answer, because it helped me too.

Comment: You're right: transformed my previous comment into an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved in the following way:

```
var myStyle = {fill: true,fillColor: "#ff0000"};
var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('CODLayer', {style: myStyle});
```

taking example from [here](http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/ollatency.html).